# Rails routes seem to be out of sync

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I just added Devise for auth and want to be able to logout my user from the url so I changed the Devise config to use `:get` instead of `:delete`.  When I look at `rake routes` it appears to be correct:

```
/sites/veggies/vegj $ rake routes
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                       Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)          devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)          devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)         devise/sessions#destroy
```

But when I try to log out in my app, I get a routing error that says `/users/sign_out` is mapped to `DELETE`.

[image]

I'm just getting started with rails so maybe this is a very basic problem.  It feels like I need to reload something, but I thought rails/rake handles updates like this on the fly, no?

Comment: updates to things in config/initializers are not picked up without a restart

Comment: @FrederickCheung the routes are located at `config/routes.rb`.. not in the initializers!

Comment: but the setting to tell devise to use :get for signouts is in config/initializers/devise.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After change made to `initializers/devise.rb` you need to restart server. They wont be picked up automatically.

PS:

there are not much of things not being picked up automatically, these are most of them

- New gems(after you do bundle install)
- generated files after you start your server(e.g. installed new gem, started server, ran gem generator)
- `initializers/*.rb` files
- `config/application.rb, config/environment.rb`

There might be some extra files i forgot to add, but in 95% cases you will change only files above.

Comment: Ok, I guess I need to learn what is (and what is not) picked up by rails.  Do you happen to know of any good references?

Comment: @doub1ejack Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Avdept, that is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a get request, as the error says.  You need to specify in your link that you want to use the delete method.

`<%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>`

Make sure you have `JQuery-ujs` in your gemfile.

Comment: According to the output for `rake routes` I should not need to use the `DELETE` method though, should I?  "`destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)`"

Comment: That is not what your screenshot shows.  I assume that is the default for devise and you've edited it but not restarted your site?

Comment: Yeah, my question was why I was getting two different routes (`rake routes` vs screenshot).  Apparently it's because I don't have a good grasp on what does (and does not) require a restart yet.  If you know of a good breakdown of what rails does & doesn't auto-detect, I'm all ears : )

Comment: @doub1ejack routing changes wouldn't normally require one.

Answer (score 0):

`destroy_user_session_path` or '/users/sign_out' is should be delete not a get request so while defining link you need to mention it as by default it will take `get request` by using `method: :delete` you pointing that it is a `delete request`.

it will take DELETE request

```
<%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

It will take GET request

```
<%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path  %>
```